# Page crashes with no clue why

Tags: php, html, crash

I have a webpage weblup(dot)net/templates/template3 (replace (dot) with a '.') and it just crashes when I run it. It was working fine not long ago but I have no clue why it's crashing all of a sudden. The biggest change before this happened was that I changed a picture.

Comment: please add the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: Turn on error output  `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and check your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your Website](http://www.weblup.net/templates/template3/) have error in logo.png and it's to big to load in website. (16620 x 9333 pixels). 
Solution: Change Your Image and resolution Image

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I actually recently had that logo designed and didn't even think about checking the resolution. Toned it way down and website is working just fine again